# Line Disappears When Using Contours in MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib

This MWE demonstrates the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

n = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, n)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.zeros((n, n))

for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(n):
        Z[j, i] = x[i] + 10.0*y[j]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')

# add line x + y = 1
ax.plot(X[X + Y == 1], Y[X + Y == 1], Z[X + Y == 1], '--r')

# add contours, comment this to make line above appear
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=np.min(Z))

plt.show()
```

With the line `cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=np.min(Z))` commented out, the image is

[image]

But I want to add contours, and when we add that line back in, the dotted line disappears:

[image]

What gives?  Also, is there a better way to add contours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the ordering of different elements; when I set `zorder` to some high value in `ax.plot` it does work:

```
ax.plot(X[X + Y == 1], Y[X + Y == 1], Z[X + Y == 1], '--r', zorder=10)
```

[image]